# Custom knowledge base: Need your views

Tags: api, metadata-api, knowledge, articles

I am working on creating custom knowledge base for one of my client. They don't want to use "Knowledge User License". I can see if we don't give "Knowledge User License" along with "Manage Article" permission then we can't perform CRUD on knowledge standard objects. We can only do SOQL on them.

Is there any way though which I can do CRUD though API on the knowledge standard objects without using knowledge user license ? Seems the Ans is No, but just want to confirm it.

If it is not possible to use standard KB objects in the back-end then do I need to go complete custom approach to create knowledge base or any other approach which can help me here.

Comment: Your client should consider the tradeoff between licensing Knowledge and getting _included_ the benefits of any future SFDC R&D investment in Knowledge, especially its integration with Service Cloud and Community versus spending money on a custom solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowledge User License are required if you want to do CRUD on Knowledge object. You need licences.

Even with the API, you can't do anything without licence.

The only thing you can do is to expose articles to people just for reading articles (ex: Community or Knowledge Widget on Service Cloud).

Sorry for you and your client, but if they don't want to pay for Knowledge Licences, you will be very limited...

I've exposed Knowledge API for external use, but without licence, external systems can't do anything on my articles.

Comment: Thanks Fabien, my understanding was also same but just want some confirmation on this. Do you think customizing the whole knowledge base would be easy thing to do or feasible. Like if we go and design the custom schema for getting the same functionality? I know it is not recommended but I want to put clear picture in front of the client.

Comment: At the end, with patience and force you will be able to do something that approach Knowledge feature. But in my opinion (as a developer), if something already exists, it's a shame to reinvent the wheel :p.
You will lost many functionnalities...

If your client don't want to pay for that feature, take a look of "CMS Content" and do a Wordpress XD